# response to telnet codes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, hex, telnet

I am using C sockets for telnet for the fun of it.

Right after `connect()`ing to the server, I `recv()` this:

In hexadecimal:

> ffffffff fffffffd 1
>   ffffffff fffffffd 21
>   ffffffff 0 ffffffa4
>   ffffff81 0 0

In decimal:

> 255 253 1
>   255 253 21
>   255 0 164
>   129 0 0

I cannot find any manual that talks about 0, 164, and 129. Can anybody explain it? Have I converted the hexadecimal wrong?

Answer (score 3):

These are TELNET option negotiating sequences, the basic set of which were originally defined in various RFCs including [RFC854](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html), [RFC855](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc855.html), and [RFC857](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc857.html).

For example the sequence:

```
255 253 1
```

Corresponds to

```
IAC DO ECHO
```

[This link](http://www.thoughtproject.com/libraries/telnet/Reference/RFCs.htm) has a good list of the relevant RFCs.